# Focusing on 1 subject means deletion of other posts?

Tags: seo, wordpress, branding

I decided to focus **only Wordpress topics** on my blog. But before this decision, I created several posts very unrelated to Wordpress such as conspiracy posts and health. This is like a minor rebranding of my website.

My problem is, these conspiracy posts got very trending and has many social likes and **dominated my WMT queries**. **My Wordpress posts got only 3-4 queries** in a day.

Should I delete those unrelated topics for the sake of SEO?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can do what they like on their sites and as far as I am concerned and this should be okay, but that is not the reality in search. If performance is a priority, it is often best to choose a topic and stick with it. You can choose related topics that compliment the primary topic, and if done well, this could increase performance especially for long-tail keywords or trend searches.

However, as you mentioned, the additional topics would likely muddy the search waters for you. While we like to think each page performs on it's own, Google still tries to establish the site topic as it should. There seems to be little tolerance for divergent topics. If your site appears to be more toward conspiracy due to activity, I would suspect that Google would take your Wordpress topics as a more minor topic. Also consider that perceived quality of any topic. This is often a factor that people forget to weigh. Your conspiracy content may fall into this category.

Personally, I would remove these topics from your site, but if you still want to explore these topics, perhaps they would be better served on a sub-domain per topic. There is a bleed through from any sub-domain to the parent domain in performance metrics, but as far as I know, Google still treats sub-domains as a separate site over all. You should be okay moving the content to a sub-domain each. If you chose to drop the topics or move them to a sub-domain, you should see a performance increase over a period of a couple of months. Unfortunately, search engines are notoriously slow for a good and rational reason.